# DrRacket:application: not a procedure Error on R5RS language

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

this is my first day on `Dr.Racket` and `R5RS` language. I'm trying to modify the existing code I share below.

```
;; This is an internal helper procedure.
;;  - it gets the method out of "in-object"
;;  - it invokes the method, passing "for-object" as the
;;    "self" for the method.                    
;;                  
(define (apply-method in-object for-object message args)
  (let ((method (get-method message in-object)))
    (cond ((method? method)                 
           (apply method for-object args))
          ((eq? in-object for-object)
       (display method)                 
           (error "No method for" message 'in
          (safe-ask 'UNNAMED-OBJECT
                in-object 'NAME)))
          (else (error "Can't delegate" message
                       "from" (safe-ask 'UNNAMED-OBJECT
                    for-object 'NAME)
               "to" (safe-ask 'UNNAMED-OBJECT
                      in-object 'NAME))))))


(define (get-method message object) ; single-inheritance
  (object message))
```

This snippet is the part of considerably huge project. Therefore, I share only the related part. Inside the project, when this `apply-method` procedure is called. I got error on the line that starts with `let` expression. The error message is as the following:

> objsys.scm:53:2: application: not a procedure;  expected a procedure
>   that can be applied to arguments
>   given: #f
>   arguments...:

[image: error message caption]

So, I wonder if is there anyone who can help me to solve the problem.
**EDIT**

I suspect that there is a syntactic error like misused or unaligned paranthesis above but I cannot find the exact place that cause error.

Comment: It looks like the problem lies more in the use of `apply-method` than in its implementation. Somewhere, it's applied with an `in-object` that is `#f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have used `apply-method` the value of `in-object` is `#f`. When `apply-method` tries to do `(get-method message in-object)` `get-method` then applies `(in-object message)` that turns into `(#f 'some-unknown-message)` and since `#f` is **not** a procedure racket has problems treating it as one and ends up with an error telling you that during application the given value `#f` is not a procedure.

Since you are using racket, perhaps you should just start the debugger and put a breakpoint on `get-method` and you'll see it. Note that Scheme and Racket languages has only one namespace for all bindings so you cannot have a procedure and a variable by the same name since a named procedure would occupy the very same variable.